# Can the sbt-crossproject plugin support two Scala.js builds with two separate main classes, both with output managed by the scalajs-bundler plugin?

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js, scalajs-bundler, sbt-crossproject

Suppose that you have a Scala.js project that compiles meaningfully to browser JavaScript, Node.js, and JVM.

Now imagine that in the browser, part of the application runs in the window while another part runs in a web worker.

Can SBT bundle two versions of the source code?  One version has a main class for the browser window, while the other has a different main class that runs the web worker code?

If so, how would you configure this?

Please note that the project depends on JavaScript native libraries and webpack.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer now, so: you can do it, either by a) defining 2 sbt `project`s, each with their own `main` class, depending on a third shared project that contains everything else; or b) defining an additional *configuration* in the sbt project (starting point: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Advanced-Configurations-Example.html + `inConfig(MyCompile)(ScalaJSPlugin.compileConfigSettings)`).

Comment: Thanks.  Do you think it makes more sense to refactor the code base into separate projects with common dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing exactly that in one of my projects, but with a `main`-class only for the JVM. The browser loads the transpiled scalajs-code and a small hook method, triggered by a js-file, initializing the core, with different parameters. This does work for `Webworker` and Frontend-thread and even for a `SharedWorker`

This could look like that:

```
importScripts("client-fullopt.js");
importScripts("conf/app-config.js");

MyProject.WebWorkerActorParent.initBackend(myProjectConfig);
MyProject.WebWorkerActorParent.addWorker(this);
```

at the frontend it could be a global script import and another initialization routine.

```
<script src='client-fullopt.js' />
<script>
  MyProject.WebWorkerActorParent.initFrontend();
</script>
```

Of course, nothing prevents you to additionally create different subprojects in `sbt`, that all use the same, common library-project and bundle their specific needs for the target platform in a separate project.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  Sorry it took so long to accept the answer.  Any new insights?